# How to send email by AWS SES: SignatureDoesNotMatch error

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ses

I'm using exact same code as in [the official example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/ses-example-send-email.html).

The only thing I changed: `from` and `to` emails and I've added credentials:

```
svc := ses.New(sess, &aws.Config{
    Credentials: credentials.NewStaticCredentials(awsSesID, awsSesSecret, ""),
})
```

where `awsSesID` is 20-character long key and `awsSessSecret` is 44-long string.
Both were obtained in the console when pressing SES > SMTP Settings > "Create SMTP credentials".

As a result I'm getting the following error:

```
SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided.
Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
```

Any guesses what I'm doing wrong?